# EntityFramework Core Subquery

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework Core and not sure how to translate below SQL query to use EF.  Below is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Project
WHERE Project_Id IN(

    SELECT Project_Id
    FROM IP
    GROUP BY Project_Id
    HAVING COUNT(Project_Id)<= 2
)
```

I have tried below script, but returns all the records from the project table.

```
var projs = _context.Project
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Project WHERE Project_Id IN(SELECT Project_Id FROM IP GROUP BY Project_Id HAVING COUNT(Project_Id)<= 2)")
    .ToList();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Side note: You generally get a more performant query plan if you use EXISTS or a JOIN as opposed to IN when you are querying across tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
var groupByCount = _context.IP.GroupBy(p => p.Project_Id)
                              .Select(g => new { Project_Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                              .ToList();
var Project_Ids = groupByCount.Where(p => p.Count <= 2).Select(p => p.Project_Id)
                               .ToArray(); 

var projs  = (from p in _context.Project
             where Project_Ids.Contains(p.Project_Id)
             select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code, but I received the following error:  ...could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: Did you debug and what does `groupByCount` result look like?

Comment: Please add `.ToList()` like this:  `var projs = _context.Project.Where(p => groupByCount.Any(g => g.Project_Id == p.Project_Id && g.Count <= 2)).ToList();`

Comment: I tried the revised code, but received the same error.  I dumped the groupByCount to a list:

 [
    {
        "project_Id": 1,
        "count": "3"
    },
    {
        "project_Id": 2,
        "count": "2"
    },
    {
        "project_Id": 22,
        "count": "1"
    }
]

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Terry Doll

Comment: I tried the updated answer and received this error:

System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Project>
    .Join(
        outer: __p_0, 
        inner: p => p.Project_Id, 
        outerKeySelector: pDetail => pDetail.Project_Id, 
        innerKeySelector: (p, pDetail) => new { 
            p = p, 
            pDetail = pDetail
         })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Terry Doll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207765/discussion-between-phong-and-terry-doll).

Answer (score 1):

If I guess your ER model right this should work:

```
_context.Project.Where(proj=> proj.IP.Count <= 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, but IP is another db context and not a field.

Comment: In the accepted answer it uses the same context (_context), so they must be in the same context, and by your sql both table are in the same database. Why don't you add the foreign key on project_id in db, it should have it anyway, with that FK in place you can use IP (or IPs) as a navigation property and my line of code would work. That's one of the superpowers of EF, you don't need to write complicated queries.